# Created(entity) throw exception with composite key

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-web-api-odata, odata-v4

I have an entity (`MyEntity`) that uses a composite key.

The entity is posted and inserted just fine, however when `Created()` is called it throws an `InvalidOperationException` with the message.

> The edit link builder for the entity set 'MyEntity' returned null. An
>   edit link is required for the location header.

```
public IHttpActionResult Post(MyEntity entity)
{
    entity = Repository.Insert(entity);
    Repository.Save();

    return Created(entity); // fails
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you build the Edm model from convention model builder, it should work.

---

```
private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
{
      var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
      ...
      return builder.GetEdmModel();
}
```

---

2. if you build the Edm model from non-convention model builder, you should set the Id link builder then it can work:

---

```
private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel2()
{
    var builder = new ODataModelBuilder();
    ...
    builder.EntitySet<MyEntity>("MyEntitys").HasEditLink(p => new Uri("http://anylink/"), false);

    return builder.GetEdmModel();
}
```

---